# Generate multiple data in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to create a button that able to generate multiple data into grid in Acumatica. Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: Generating element]

Based on the figure above, if I press button (number 1), the grid (number 2) will filled automatically for certain amount of data, is this possible in Acumatica? Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess the simple answer is yes. You can use just about any master detail page for an example. If the data at the top is entered vs selected then you can use a filter for that data (no single record loaded) and then the button would fill in the data into the grid below with actual records. Without code examples its hard to really answer this question as its very generic short of performing a working sample for you.

Comment: Yes definitely possible, the 'FormGrid' page template should get you started. Then add an action button. In the button event handler, you insert new records in the grid 'detail' dataview.

Comment: @Brendan I don't have code example yet, because I am just thinking an approach

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA Is there any resources that I can use as reference on how to insert new multiple records at the same time, and add the auto numbering for it if possible?

Comment: It is covered in T200 training material: http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/courses/development/t200-acumatica-framework-fundamentals/

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be yes and here is the design pattern.

Assumptions:  You have a graph, and publicly declared a PXSelect on MyLineDac as Lines;

```
public PXSelect<MyLineDac , Where<...>> Lines;
```

Under the button press event:

Clear out the current lines if needed

```
foreach (MyLineDac oldline this.Lines.Select())
            {
                this.Lines.Delete(oldline);
            }
```

Populate lines:

```
foreach (MyDacSourceLines lineadd in
            PXSelectReadonly<MyDacSourceLines,
            Where<........>>>.Select(this, row.RefValueIfweHaveRequiredFields)
            )
        {
           MyLineDac newline = new MyLineDac();
            newline.No = lineadd.No;
            newline.SubElement = lineadd.SubElement;              
            newline = this.Lines.Insert(newline);
        }
```